Connect to legacy Informix Server using .NET Data Provider
I am creating an IfxConnection to connect to the legacy Informix server
IfxConnection con = new IfxConnection("Host=localhost;Server=myserver;UID=user;Pwd=pswd;Service=9088;Database=sysmaster")

Connection string with this set of parameters was working with some old Informix CSDK back then, but now con.Open() throws an exception "Invalid argument", and unfortunately does not say which argument exactly.
I have tried to add/remove connection string parameters in many combinations, including using parameters like Persist Security Info, Authentication, DB_LOCALE, CLIENT_LOCALE, Protocol and so on, but no luck.
Could anyone please provide a valid connection string or give me a hint what am I doing wrong?

I see nothing wrong with that connection string. All those parameters are valid for the Informix .NET Provider (CSDK's IBM.Data.Informix.dll). Is that the one you are using? Back in the days (Informix 11.10) there was another IBM.Data.Informix.dll which was shipped with the IBM Data Server .NET Provider (which uses the DB2/DRDA protocol). That one has a different set of parameters, for example, the server keyword is not needed and may throw that error. Regarding  legacy servers, even the latest CSDK 4.50.FC10W1 will still work against old servers.

If you are trying to connect without defining the Informix server connection details in the sqlhosts file, you will need to add protocol=onsoctcp in your connection string (sesoctcp for an Informix Standard Engine)

I have found answer thanks to comment from jsagrera
There are two versions of IBM.Data.Informix.dll - one from DB2, and another from Informix CSDK, and I was accidentally using DB2 one, because it was installed in GAC in my machine.
Version from Informix CSDK works just fine with the connection string provided.
